no store found. make sure to follow instruction in chrome redux toolkit

screenshot here actually i m new to this react and redux and i recently stated a project using react project using redux.. and the problem is the redux devTool chrome extension was working perfectly in initial days but i got "no store found. make sure to follow instruction" screen for last 3 days. but i m getting the store data in my application components
i have tried reconfigure the redux store followed by some youtube video but that was not working well in my cases and again i reinstalled the redux toolkit from chrome extension.. no luck.. someone please help
here is my code
package.json
{
  "name": "fresshkart",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.3",
    "rc-slider": "^11.1.5",
    "rc-tooltip": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.8",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-helmet-async": "^2.0.5",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "allowedHosts": "all",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
}

index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import store from "./store"
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

store.js
import {configureStore,combineReducers} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {thunk} from 'redux-thunk'
import productsReducer from "./slices/productsSlice";
import productReducer from "./slices/productSlice";
import authReducer from './slices/authSlice';


 
const reducer = combineReducers({
    productsState : productsReducer,
    productState : productReducer,
    authState : authReducer
})


const store = configureStore({
    reducer, 
    /* middleware :  getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
      thunk: {
        extraArgument: ''
      } 
    })  */
    
})


export default store;


Have you reloaded the current page you are on so the redux-devtools can maybe re-source a store, or ensure you have selected an instance that corresponds to your React app's page?

The configureStore function handles the combineReducers for you, so there's no need to call it manually.
Here the how updated store should look like :
const store = configureStore({
    productsState : productsReducer,
    productState : productReducer,
    authState : authReducer  
})

And I hope you are exporting reducers like this in your slice files
export default productsSlice.reducer

export default productReducer.reducer

export default authReducer.reducer

Finally your store should be like this
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {thunk} from 'redux-thunk'
import productsReducer from "./slices/productsSlice";
import productReducer from "./slices/productSlice";
import authReducer from './slices/authSlice';


const store = configureStore({
    productsState : productsReducer,
    productState : productReducer,
    authState : authReducer,
    /* middleware :  getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
      thunk: {
        extraArgument: ''
      } 
    })  */
    
})


export default store;


You can most certainly combine your reducers into a root reducer to be passed in the configureStore's configuration object. OP's code is fine in this regard. Your code, however, is passing invalid properties in the configuration parameters. This doesn't answer the question as to why or how the store isn't seen or is not available to the Redux-Devtools browser extension.
